# Why bash converting double quotes to single quotes?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a simple test script having the below code

```
#!/bin/bash
CHM=test
NAME="user@test"
if ! grep -q test /etc/passwd
then
        useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/test -c "${CHM} : ${NAME}" test
fi
```

but I'm having problem with bash converting my " to ' example output

```
+ CHM=test
+ NAME=user@test
+ grep -q test /etc/passwd
+ useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/test -c 'test : user@test' test
useradd: invalid comment 'test : user@test'
```

I can't figure how to fix this any input is welcome, try to search but does not yield any preferred result

OS: RHEL6
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thanks

Comment: What is your requirement? How do you want the name to be added?

Comment: if you see the output the useradd command will not accept -c 'text' it only accept -c "text"

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu. Which OS is this?

Comment: I'm using redhat 6, bash version GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: @Inian try that but it will resulted incorrect syntax too: + useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/test -c '"test' : 'user@test"' test

Comment: @Inian that wierd that because when useradd still not accepting single quote it command `+ useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/test -c '"test' : 'user@test"' test` I'm seeing bash doing this **-c '"test' : 'user@test"'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` is delimited by `:` character and hence useradd is rejecting the comment. Try removing `:` in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't convert any quotes, this is purely an output artifact of `set -x`. As you can see, the `${VARIABLES}` have been expanded in the `set -x` output. After that the quote type no longer matters and the bash maintainer chose to display all words containing blanks in single quotes to make the word boundaries clear.

The actual problem, as codegrep_admin correctly identified, is the impossibility to use a colon `:` for any field in `/etc/passwd`. E.g. you can't have a user named `foo:bar` and you can't have a comment saying `test:user@test` and you can't have a shell named `ba:sh`.